# Setup of the number of custom frame ticks

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

Below I give the definition of custom ticks

```
ticksHelper[min_, max_] := 
 Module[{out = 
Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][min, max] // #[[;; , {1, 2}]] & // Cases[#, {_, _?NumberQ}] &}, 
If[First@Last@out < max, AppendTo[out, {max, "> " <> ToString@max}],
out[[-1, -1]] = "> " <> ToString@max];
out]
```

and this is a simple example

```
min = 0;
max = 5;
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, ticksHelper[min, max]}}]
```

[image]

We see that 6 ticks are printed, which is fine.

Now if we change to range to

```
min = 0;
max = 3;
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, ticksHelper[min, max]}}]
```

[image]

only two ticks are printed.

In my case, `min` is always 0, while `max` can always be divided by 5 (i.e., `min` equals to 0.5, 3, 5, etc).

I want always six labels to be printed inside the given range. For example, if `max` equals to 0.5 I want the ticks (0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5), while if `max` equals to 2.5 I want the ticks (0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5).

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: See `FindDivisions`. The charting function is good if you don't know in advance a decent way to subdivide your range.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I did not developed these custom ticks, so I really don;t know what changes should be done in the module. Any specific suggestions would be great!

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't be more specific right now, but I suggest comparing the output of the Charting`ScaledTicks[...][...] vs. FindDivisions[{min, max}, 6]

Comment: @LLlAMnYP It does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll expand on my comment.

```
charting[min_, max_] := Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][min, max]
  // #[[;; , {1, 2}]] & // Cases[#, {_, _?NumberQ}] &
```

is in some respects equivalent to

```
finddivs[min_, max_] := FindDivisions[{min, max}, 6]
```

For example

```
charting[1.1, 5.9]
finddivs[1.1, 5.9]
charting[0.9, 6.1]
finddivs[0.9, 6.1]
```

returns:

```
{{2., 2}, {3., 3}, {4., 4}, {5., 5}}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
{{1., 1}, {2., 2}, {3., 3}, {4., 4}, {5., 5}, {6., 6}}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Neither of them is exact; Mathematica does not find intervals like `{0., 0.6, 1.2, 2.4, 3.0}` to be "nice".

Given your specification (numbers divisible by 5, starting from 0), the easiest is to do:

```
sixTicks[max_] := Transpose[{#, #}] &[Range[0., max, max/5]
```

and to modify `ticksHelper` like so:

```
ticksHelper[min_, max_] := 
  Module[{out = sixTicks[max]}, 
out[[-1, -1]] = "> " <> ToString@max;
out]
```

**Update 10.03.17**

At first I suggested an undocumented, internal function

```
Charting`ScaledTicks
```

to generate the necessary ticks semi-automatically and then to post-process the output to get the more detailed specifications required by the OP. Usually -- when working internally -- this function takes the plot range and generates a nice set of ticks for that range. E.g.,

```
(Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][-0.132, 1.145]
    // #[[;; , ;; 2]] &               (* strips tick style specs *)
  // DeleteCases[#, {_, _Spacer}] &)  (* removes minor ticks *)
```

> ```
> {{0.,0},{0.25,0.25},{0.5,0.50},{0.75,0.75},{1.,1.00}}
> ```

This leaves us with a very simple list of `{position, label}` tuples. Note, how I fed the function an awkward range like `(-0.132, 1.145)` but it tried to return a list of sufficiently round numbers. By the way, it also formatted each number to have two digits after the decimal. Peeking at the `FullForm` we can see that the `0.50` (list element `[[3,2]]`) is actually

```
NumberForm[0.5, {DirectedInfinity[1], 2}]
```

As I have mentioned, `FindDivisions[{min, max}, n]` does a similar thing, subdividing a given range into approximately `n` intervals.

This is of somewhat limited use for the OP, since these automatic functions -- among other things -- may or may not indeed include a tick at `max`.

When fine control is desired, there are packages for this, such `CustomTicks` and/or for such a specific use case it may be easier to simply roll a quick function. Hopefully, this update will describe in enough detail, *how* to do it, rather than just do it.

As mentioned before, OP has

```
min = 0;
max = ...;
```

where max (or perhaps, rather, `10 * max`) is divisible by 5. To properly describe the procedure, I'll verbosely rewrite the helper functions `sixTicks` and `ticksHelper`.

First we need the positions of the ticks, which I immediately generate to machine precision; these are quite simply `{0, max/5, 2max/5, ...}` or

```
positions = Range[0., max, max/5];
```

Next, we need the labels at these positions. I, generally, prefer casting them to strings, like so:

```
labels = ToString /@ positions
```

and then the ticks will be

```
Transpose[{positions, labels}]
```

There's two things to handle: OP wants the last tick label to be `> max`, which is trivially done by

```
labels[[-1]] = "> " <> labels[[-1]]
```

OP also wants the numbers to have equal number of digits after the decimal point, which is slightly harder. In fact, a very quick search couldn't find an easy way to ask Mathematica

> Ok, we have a machine-precision number like `0.0032`. Sure, the precision of it is `15.84` or so, but how many digits are there really, for us humans?

and to get the obvious answer `4`. Well, one quick and dirty approach is to multiply by 10, compare the result to `Floor[result]`, if not, multiply by 10 again, and so on.

```
Length[NestWhileList[10 # &, 0.25, Floor@# != # &]] - 1
Length[NestWhileList[10 # &, 0.0032, Floor@# != # &]] - 1
(* 2 *)
(* 4 *)
```

We know for sure, that the longest decimal representation of our list of numbers will be no longer than the representation of `max/5`. So let's start putting all this together in a `Module`

```
ticks[max_] := Module[
  {
    positions = Range[0., max, max / 5],
    precision = Length[NestWhileList[10 # &, max / 5, Floor@# != # &]] - 1,
    labels},
  If[precision > 0, 
    labels = ToString /@ (NumberForm[#, {Infinity, precision}] & /@ positions)];
  If[precision == 0,
    labels = ToString /@ Floor[positions]];
  labels[[-1]] = "> " <> labels[[-1]];
  Transpose[{positions, labels}]
]
```

Most things here I've covered. To get the correct formatting of numbers, I've borrowed the function used in the output of `` Charting`ScaledTicks ``, i.e. `NumberForm`. `NumberForm[0.016, {Infinity, 4}]` will print `0.016` with 4 digits to the right of the decimal, i.e. `0.0160`. The two `If` statements handle the special case that all labels are integers, so `Floor` turns machine-preicsion numbers like `1.` into integers like `1`. For integers `NumberForm` is unnecessary.

```
Plot[Sin[200 x], {x, -0.02, 0.02},
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, ticks[0.016]}}]
```

[image]

I hope, this answer doesn't give the fish, but also the fishing rod.

Comment: It works however there is a minor issue. For example when `max = 10` the ticks are 0. 2. 4. 6. 8. > 10, while I would like to be 0 2 4 6 8 > 10. This is doable if I set `[Range[0, max, max/5]`. On the other hand when `max = 4` it prints 0 0.8 1.6 2.4 etc. I want the following: when there are no decimal digits to print the numbers without the dots (2 instead of 2.), while when there are decimal digits to print the zero with the same number of decimal digits (i.e., 0.0 instead of 0.). Is this possible?

Comment: @vag This is certainly possible with a pattern - matching construct, i.e. look for reals/rationals. It's mildly out of scope, but if no one answers this, I'll expand the answer tomorrow. (I'm on mobile again)

Comment: Take your time and update your answer if possible. It would be very nice to have ticks with equal number of decimal digits, just for consistency!

Comment: @Vaggelis I see this is your second question over a couple of days about ticks. I think, it would be best if I add a separate, somewhat more general answer about ticks and specifications, etc.

Comment: That would be very nice. It would be also useful if the suggested solution is compatible with earlier versions of Mathematica (i.e., v9.0).

Comment: @Vaggelis Well, I hope this update helps, I decided to keep stuff in one answer.

Comment: Your updated solution works well except for one case. For example when all the custom ticks have no decimal digits (e.g., when `max = 5`) it prints 0. 1. 2. etc, while I would like to have clean numbers 0 1 2 3 etc. Is this doable?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z thanks for the heads up, I forgot about that. Updating...

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z fixed

Comment: Now everything is just fine! I wish I could accept twice or more your answer!

Answer (score 3):

At least starting from version 10 `` Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}] `` accepts second argument which allows to specify the number of major and minor ticks in the range. For example, `7` or `{7, 1}` as the second argument switches off generation of minor ticks and requests about 7 "nice" numbers that divide the interval into equally spaced parts:

```
Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##, {7, 1}] &[0, .5]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0, {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
>  {0.1, 0.1, {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
>  {0.2, NumberForm[0.2, {Infinity, 1}], {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
>  {0.3, NumberForm[0.3, {Infinity, 1}], {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
>  {0.4, NumberForm[0.4, {Infinity, 1}], {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
>  {0.5, NumberForm[0.5, {Infinity, 1}], {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}}
> ```

Note that all the numbers (except `0`) are formatted with equal number of digits  to the right of the decimal point:

```
Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][0, .05, {10, 1}][[;; , ;; 2]]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0}, 
>  {0.005, NumberForm[0.005, {Infinity, 3}]}, 
>  {0.01, NumberForm[0.01, {Infinity, 3}]}, 
>  {0.015, NumberForm[0.015, {Infinity, 3}]}, 
>  {0.02, NumberForm[0.02, {Infinity, 3}]}, 
>  {0.025, NumberForm[0.025, {Infinity, 3}]}, 
>  {0.03, NumberForm[0.03, {Infinity, 3}]}, 
>  {0.035, NumberForm[0.035, {Infinity, 3}]}, 
>  {0.04, NumberForm[0.04, {Infinity, 3}]}, 
>  {0.045, NumberForm[0.045, {Infinity, 3}]}, 
>  {0.05, NumberForm[0.05, {Infinity, 3}]}}
> ```

---

Here is how the above can be incorporated into your `ticksHelper` function:

```
ticksHelper[min_, max_] := 
 Module[{out = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][min, max, 6][[;; , ;; 2]]}, 
  If[out[[-1, 1]] < max, AppendTo[out, {max, "> " <> ToString@max}], 
   out[[-1, -1]] = "> " <> ToString@max];
  out]

min = 0;
max = 3;
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, ticksHelper[min, max]}}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: Can you incorporate your solution into the `ticksHelper` module of the original post?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I updated the answer.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z so having 5 or 7 ticks is also acceptable?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Well, anything between 5 and 7 ticks is acceptable.